# The nimbus-jose-jwt and io.jsonwebtoken - which jjwt library to pick and why?

Tags: java, jjwt

I am looking to implement the **jjwt** in my application and looking to implement jjwt, when I googled I found these two maven dependency not sure which one to pick and why ?

```
<jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and other is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have played POC with both the API library, but not sure which one will be the extensible solution. I am developing `Spring MVC` + `Spring Security` + `Spring REST` + `HATEOAS` + `CORS` + `Spring Batch` and all backend code will be deployed on the `tomcat` and front-end is `AngularJS` will be deployed on the nodejs.

Hope this info will be sufficient to answer the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are not going to create JWT token and only need to consume it in Spring then you dont really need any of libraries. Spring will take care of validating and decoding the JWT token for you.

The only time I needed to use either libraries is when trying to generate JWT token.

The **jsonwebtoken** library was more straightforward to use and had better documentation. But I found **nimbus** library to be more feature rich and the only one that could work with JWKS.

Answer (score 4):

Nimbus is included in spring-security-oauth2-jose.
And it has a great feature that 0.x jjwt lacks at the moment - validating JWKS